# How can I render a button based on condition in html templates | Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to render the button based on a condition.

Here I am checking if the combo is in cart, then I will render out the remove button, for that combo only.

But I am not able to do that.

Here in `ComboCartItem` class `combo` field is a `ForeignKey` of class `Combo` and in `Cart` class `combo_item` field is a `ManyToManyField` of class `ComboCartItem`

So in general if we want to display a list of all the combos that are present in the cart we can do that by `{% for item in cart.combo_item.all %}{{item.combo}}{% endfor %}`

But it doesn't work while going for a condition check.

Please help.

```
{% if combo in cart.combo_item.all %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Remove?</button>
    {% endif %}
```

This doesn't work. Please help!

`l.html`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'carts:combo_add_to_cart' %}" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="combo_id" value="{{ combo.id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
    {% if combo in cart.combo_item.all %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Remove?</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

`combo - models.py`

```
class Combo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

`cart - models.py`

```
class ComboCartItem(models.Model):
    combo = models.ForeignKey(Combo, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Cart(models.Model):
    combo_item = models.ManyToManyField(ComboCartItem, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do another way to solve this by: what you are checking here with a condition do it in your views, pass it by appending into your context data and get the boolean value here and do the operations in django template.

Comment: It renders out for all the combo items that are in in the list. Suppose I have Combo 1 and Combo 2 and both have a button of add to cart. Now when I click add to cart button for combo 2 the remove button should appear for only the combo 2 not for combo 1. Since i didnt added the item in the cart

Comment: just send the only combo items you need from view to template in a context data and all the combos in an another context data. It will be very easy for you distinguish also.